# Parsing 2 parameter from multiple select in on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

i want to get 2 value from select option province and city in on change event, then send it to my api datatable but why i always only getting the first value while i clicked that select options for few times? this is my code

```
$(document).on('change', 'select[name="province"], select[name="city"]', function() {
    province = $('select[name="province"] option:selected').val()
    city = $('select[name="city"] option:selected').val()

    const empdataTable = new ServerSideDatatable({
      element: '#table-emp-address',
      url: '/user/user/get-data-user-address',
      postData: { 'province': province, 'city' : city }, //here i only get data province
      columns: [
        { data: 'id', name: 'id', title: 'Id', orderable: false },
        { data: 'name', name: 'name', title: 'Name', orderable: true },
        { data: 'Province', name: 'Province', title: 'Province', orderable: false },
        { data: 'City', name: 'City', title: 'City', orderable: false },
      ],
      buttons: [
        { urlProperty: 'urlDetail', label: '<i class="icon-search4"></i> Detail' },
      ]
    })
    
  })
```

what wrong here?

Comment: Have you debugged that the variables `province` and `city` are correct after you retrieve them?  (ie directly after the 2x `.val()` statements).   If they're correct there then it's an issue with your `ServerSideDatatable`.   If they're not correct then, then the `ServerSideDatatable` is irrelevant.   Can you provide HTML/js/etc to *demonstrate* the issue in a snippet?

Comment: Also note that `province=...` declares a *global* variable, so if that value changes before ServerSideDatatable can use it (seems unlikely, but still) then it will be the wrong value.  Try changing to `let province = ...` and `let city = `

Comment: As provided in the question, using `$("select[name..] option:selected").val()` works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/ycs0d4wr/

Answer (score 0):

You can try initializing the province and city like below.

```
province = $('select[name="province"]').val();
city = $('select[name="city"]').val();
```

You can capture `<select>` tag values without `option:selected`

Comment: out side the on change event?

Comment: no, inside the on change (in the same line as where you have initialized the city and province)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on('change', 'select[name="province"], select[name="city"]', function() {
    province = $('select[name="province"] option:selected').val();
    city = $('select[name="city"] option:selected').val();
    
    console.log(province+'---'+city);  

// Output: 20---Indore , 30---Dubai

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="province">
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="30">30</option>
</select>
<select name="city">
  <option value="Indore">Indore</option>
  <option value="London">London</option>
  <option value="Dubai">Dubai</option>
</select>

/* Problem in ServerSideDatatable Request or getting proper value */
```

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.